# An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error)

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops, libgit2

I have run into this several times now:

```
 An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error).
```

Which sometimes causes this or similar error while i am writing code:

```
Failed to open '.../App_Data/....mdf': 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

When this happens i can't code without restarting my `Visaul Studio 2012`.

I think it's being caused by `Source Control - Git` as i don't remember having this problem before i installed the Git extension for Visual Studio and Team Foundation.

Has anyone else run into this and how did they solve it?

Comment: What's the file in question?

Comment: @EdwardThomson mostly the `.mdf` but also, i can't use certain keys on my keyboard eg: Enter key while in the source

Comment: Interesting, are your `.mdf` files in your repository?  Are they ignored via `.gitignore`?

Comment: MY `.mdf` files are in `App_Data`. Its an `MVC 4` app. And i just checked, `.mdf` is not ignored via `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran into this today with a new Visual Studio project. The project was using the autogenerated `.gitignore` which had the following entries which I thought should have covered the `.mdf` file just fine:

```
# SQL Server files
App_Data/*.mdf
App_Data/*.ldf
```

However I still received:

```
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error). 
Failed to open '.../App_Data/....mdf': 
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

So I edited the `.gitignore`, preceding each entry with an asterisk-slash, like so:

```
# SQL Server files
*/App_Data/*.mdf
*/App_Data/*.ldf
```

And I was able to continue business as usual.

Comment: This is slowing me down, i will get rid of `git` from my project

Comment: I'm getting this on .dbmdl too even though I have them .gitignored!  Really frustrating.  Works fine from Git GUI though on the same repo and if I check it all in then the VS plugin will work for a while again until it doesn't.

Comment: @uosɐſ You may have to remove the files in question from the actual repo. .gitignore ignores files going forward.

Comment: I previously deleted this .dbmdl file (as it gets regenerated) and checked in the deletion.  Doing a `git rm --cached blah.dbmdl` says that the path doesn't exist (it shows the correct path and I only have one branch).

Answer (score 3):

I would want to add it is maybe just as simple as => Close your database connexion :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error.  IIS express was running in the system tray.  When I killed IIS Express everything committed as expected.