# VS2013 - GIT not working

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I've recently installed VS2013.  Whenever I try to do anything with GIT I get the following 2 messages in the output window:

An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Unknown (Error).
No error message has been provided by the native library

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what you're trying to do and against what kind of repository? Is this when cloning from a remote repository (if so, which version of Git is that running) or against a wellknown Git host (GitHub, VSO) or a TFS2013 server?

Comment: There is a note in the Git for Visual Studio page that mentions this specific error and it says that switching branch (`checkout`) from the git commandline in your gitrepository will fix the issue (which is a known LibGit2 bug) Maybe that will work here too. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c

Comment: And there seems to be a known issue when a repository is stored on a file share: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/abafc7d6-dcaa-40f4-8a5e-d6724bdb980c/view/Discussions/6

Comment: it happens when I create a new project under source-control, or when choosing "Add solution to source control" for existing projects.

Comment: Please be a lot more specific. Are you adding this project to an exising local git repository? Does it already have a remote server configured? Can you add screenshots of what you're doing?

Comment: I am having a similar issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038238/add-solution-to-source-control-causes-error

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163104/an-error-was-raised-by-libgit2-category-os-error)

Answer (score 0):

The issue may come mainly in remote repository fetching. 
Before cloning remote repository, please open the remote url and check whether it is accessible from the local system.

For ex when i want to connect to \1.1.1.1\mygit, open this path in the command window and check if it is accessible. If the remote system is also on the same network and proper permission is given, then it will allow to connect. In case of secured networks, while opening the path, it will ask for credentials to connect to 1.1.1.1 and only after entering the credentials, we will be able to connect