# Add solution to source control causes error

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to add my visual studio project to source control. Whenever I select `'Add solution to source control'`, it displays the following message on output window.

```
Opening repository: C:\Users\myUserName. 
An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Unknown (Error).
No error message has been provided by the native library
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web.

Comment: Looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/20730228/6309

Comment: possible duplicate of [An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Os (Error)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163104/an-error-was-raised-by-libgit2-category-os-error)